# Doctrine2 - Strange behavior for special characters

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have problem with polish characters in Doctrine. When I am using code below everything works fine and I am getting one record:

```
$em->getRepository('ePOSProductsBundle:Product')->findByName('Koszulka z małpka');
```

But when I am using another code below it doesn't work and I am not getting records:

```
$products = $qb->select('p')->from('ePOSProductsBundle:Product', 'p')
      ->where("p.name LIKE '%małpka%'")
      ->getQuery()
      ->getResult();
```

Does anyone know why this is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$productName = 'małpka';
$result = $qb->select('p')
    ->from('ePOSProductsBundle:Product', 'p')
    ->where($qb->expr()->like('p.name', ':product_name'))
    ->setParameter('product_name', $product)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

Comment: doesn't work also, but the another strange thing is this that that works for other entity

Comment: It has started working when I have deleted this query and wrote it again, what is strange.

Comment: well ... perfect! then everything is nice now? maybe you had some query-cache driver like apc with a certain lifetime enabled preventing the updated query from being applied? So if my answer solved your issue please upvote/accept. happy coding :-)